# How to initialize an empty array of objects in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I have fetched a set of data documents, and am looping through them to create an object out of each called 'Item'; each Item object has an 'amount' key and an 'id' key.

I need to append each created Item object to an array called 'Items'. However, when I create this array at the top (currently like this: **var itemObjects: [Item]**) and then push each item to the array like this:

```
snapshot.forEach((doc: any) => {
let docData = doc.data()
let items = docData.items
items.forEach((item: any) => {
  let itemObject = new Item(item.amount, item.transactionType)
  console.log("converted item to Item Object:", itemObject)
  itemObjects.push(itemObject)
})
```

It gives me this error: Unhandled error TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'push')\n

I believe I am incorrectly initializing the variable array up top. Any help is appreciated thanks.

EDIT- the other piece of code (for the Item class) is:

```
interface IItem {
amount: number
id: string
}

export class Item implements IItem {
 amount: number
 id: string

 constructor(amount: number, id: string) {
  this.amount = amount
  this.id = id
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not *initializing* the variable, merely *declaring* it. After TypeScript removes the type annotations, all that is left in the resulting JavaScript is:

```
var itemObjects
```

So just give it a value:

```
var itemObjects: Item[] = []
                        ^^^^
```

The other issue (also fixed above) is that `[Item]` is a [tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types) of a single `Item`. At runtime it's just an array, but you can't create one with more or fewer than one `Item`. Instead, use `Item[]` to denote an array of items.

Comment: Type '[]' is not assignable to type '[Item]'.
  Source has 0 element(s) but target requires 1.

Comment: that is the error I get when I try initializing it in that way.

Comment: Right, see edit.

Comment: I understand your edit, but it is giving me a similar error when written that way:

Comment: Argument of type 'Item[]' is not assignable to parameter of type '[Item]'.
  Target requires 1 element(s) but source may have fewer.

Comment: That error is not originating in any code you have shown. There is no more `[Item]` anywhere and there shouldn't be.

Comment: You're right, my apologies, I edited the question above so you can see the remaining code for 'Item' class

Comment: There's still no `[Item]` anywhere in that code. If you are still having trouble, open a new question with all the necessary code to reproduce _that_ problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247227/discussion-between-ohu-and-thomas).

Answer (score 1):

You can declare a typed array like the following:

```
var items = new Array<Item>();
```

or

```
var items: Item[] = [];
```

Both ways will give you exactly same behavior.

Btw why not just use map function instead of forEach?

```
var items = docs.map((item: any) => new Item(item.amount, item.id));
```

Comment: I agree that in this case, the type is obvious and inferred by TS and I would not write it in manually.